# iOS saving images in flashbuilder air mobile app with CameraUI

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

**I have an air app for iOS I have been developing.  I am trying to capture a picture, save the file to the storage directory (not Camera Roll), and save the file name in an sqlite db.

I have tried so many different variations of this, but when it comes to writing the filestream to save the app hangs. Testing on iPad 3. Does ANYONE have a suggestion? This has been driving me nuts for days.  I have searched the web but I am stumped.**

```
      public var temp:File; // File Object to save name in database
        protected function selectPicture():void
        {
            
            myCam = new CameraUI();
            myCam.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        
            myCam.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);
        }
        
        
        protected function onComplete(event:MediaEvent):void {
        
        //imageProblem.source = event.data.file.url;
        
            var cameraUI:CameraUI = event.target as CameraUI;
            
            
            var mediaPromise:MediaPromise = event.data;
            
            var mpLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            mpLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMediaPromiseLoaded);
            
            mpLoader.loadFilePromise(mediaPromise);
            

        }
        
        private function onMediaPromiseLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var mpLoaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
            mpLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMediaPromiseLoaded);
            
            this.imageProblem.source = mpLoaderInfo.loader;
            
        
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            
            stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showComplete);
            stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, showError);
            
            
            try{
                
            this.messages.text = "Starting";
                
            stream.open( temp, FileMode.WRITE );
            stream.writeBytes(mpLoaderInfo.bytes);
            stream.close();
            
            }catch(e:Error){
            
                this.messages.text = e.message;
            
            }
            
            
        
        
        
        }
        
        protected function showError(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
            
            this.messages.text = e.toString();
            
            
        }
        
        protected function showComplete(e:Event):void{
            
            this.messages.text = "Completed Writing";
            this.imgName.text = temp.url;
            imagefile = temp;
            deleteFlag = 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work, I added comments below in the code to explain why it wasn't working.

```
                    public var temp:File;
        protected function selectPicture():void
        {

            myCam = new CameraUI();
            myCam.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);

            myCam.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);
        }


        protected function onComplete(event:MediaEvent):void {

        //imageProblem.source = event.data.file.url;

            var cameraUI:CameraUI = event.target as CameraUI;


            var mediaPromise:MediaPromise = event.data;

            var mpLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            mpLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMediaPromiseLoaded);

            mpLoader.loadFilePromise(mediaPromise);


        }

        private function onMediaPromiseLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var mpLoaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
            mpLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMediaPromiseLoaded);

            this.imageProblem.source = mpLoaderInfo.loader;




                /// Here was the solution

                var bitmapDataA:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mpLoaderInfo.width, mpLoaderInfo.height);
                bitmapDataA.draw(mpLoaderInfo.content,null,null,null,null,true);  

                /// I had to cast the loaderInfo as BitmapData 

                var bitmapDataB:BitmapData = resizeimage(bitmapDataA, int(mpLoaderInfo.width / 4), int(mpLoaderInfo.height/ 4));  // function to shrink the image





                var c:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
                c.addBitmapData(bitmapDataB);

                var now:Date = new Date();
                var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("IMG" + now.seconds + now.minutes + ".jpg");                                    
                var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
                stream.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);                                         

                // Then had to redraw and encode as a jpeg before writing the file


                var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                bytes = bitmapDataB.encode(new Rectangle(0,0, int(mpLoaderInfo.width / 4) , int(mpLoaderInfo.height / 4)), new JPEGEncoderOptions(80), bytes);




                stream.writeBytes(bytes,0,bytes.bytesAvailable);
                stream.close(); 

                this.imgName.text = f.url;


            imagefile = f;
            deleteFlag = 1;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Application hangs due to you are trying to use file operation in `Sync mode`.

You need to use `Async Mode` operation instead of sync mode file operation.

```
stream.openAsync( temp, FileMode.WRITE );
```

Try with this

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showComplete);
stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, showError);
stream.openAsync( temp, FileMode.WRITE );
stream.writeBytes(mpLoaderInfo.bytes);
stream.close();
```

Note when using async operation you need not use `try catch`.For handling error listen IOErrorEvent will catch if any error occurs.

Comment: Actually I did try the Async method as well.  It still produced the same result.  The try catch block was for me to see if I was getting an error during writing.. But I certainly appreciate the help